# About Quine-McCluskey method on circuit design and don't cares

Tags: digital-logic

My teacher have give me a question is like this.

> Design a 2-of-5 Code to BCD 8421 Code converter. Minimize each of the output to SOP form using Q-M method and draw the circuit diagram using basic gates (i.e. AND, OR, NOT gates).

Can I treat the non [2-of-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-out-of-five_code) code output as logic 0 insteat of don't-care terms? because I dont have any idea how to do the [QM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine-McCluskey) method without error with 22 dont care term. =.='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Since she didn't specify what to do with invalid input, you can do what you wish. However using don't cares will result in a smaller result.